# Associations confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Scenario:

Example:

A seller decides to sell a BMW. Before selling a particular model of the BMW (say a 7-series 760 Li) a CarSketch needs to be created by the seller. This CarSketch belongs to the BMW, in here we get specifications about the BMW. This CarSketch also has a quick summary of the physical information of the BMW ( length, etc ) represented as a Presentation.

Thus, If I want to sell a BMW. a model 540 and a model 760.

```
# car_sketch_for_model_540 = CarSketch obj
# presentation_for_model_540 = Presentation obj

# car_sketch_for_model_760 = CarSketch obj
# presentation_for_model_760 = Presentation obj
```

the seller approves and starts selling the BMW car, model 540 and 760. That is, the buyers sees a list of Presentations only.

Since the car can have many buyers, a buyer will only choose (buy) one model (presentation).

The CarSketch model is used by the seller for internal stuff. When browsing the site, the buyer can see the available models to buy because rails looks at the presentations through the CarSketch model.

For each buyer interested in a particular model (Presentation), a Buyer record is added pointing to a presentation.

I have a problem trying to figure out how to set up these associations on Rails. Basically I have 4 models. Let's call these Car, CarSketch, Presentation, and Buyer.

1. Car can have many CarSketch's
2. CarSketch contains a foreign key for one Presentation. There could be 2 rows under CarSketch referencing one Presentation, too.
3. There can be any number of Presentation records.
4. Buyer contains a foreign key for one Presentation. There could be 2 rows under Buyer referencing one Presentation, too.
5. CarSketch and Buyer have foreign keys to reference Car.

> Car->CarSketch->Presentation
> Car->Buyer->Presentation

How do I express (associations) Presentation with CarSketch and Buyer?!?

Is this correct?

```
class CarSketch < ActiveRecord::Base    
    belongs_to :presentation
end

class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :presentation
end

#what to do here?
class Presentation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :car_sketches
    has_many :buyers
end
```

I don't care about the records created at Presentation, really.

I want to be able to have:

```
#assume presentation is a Presentation record...

CarSketch.presentation = defined
Buyer.presentation = some other presentation

also, CarSketch and Buyer could point to the same Presentation record.
```

Help is appreciated!

Personally, even though the current one works. It just doesn't make sense when I read it... CarSketch and Buyer are join tables... created by me since I need to hold more attributes for them...

It doesn't make sense that a CarSketch **belongs** to a Presentation because any number of CarSketch can have one presentation and **a presentation doesn't have many CarSketch** See what I'm saying?

Or is it normal to get confused like these when defining your own join tables as models and these referencing other models?

I'm not interested in using Presentation directly to retrieve CarSketch or Buyer.

**UPDATE**

#### Heavily edited to replace A B C D with the corresponding names.

#### OP, please check.

```
UPDATE*

# A = Car
# B = CarSketch
# C = Presentation

# D = Buyer

# 1) a Car can have many car_sketches.
# 2) a CarSketch has one Presentation.
# 3) a Car can also have many buyers.
# 4) a Buyer has one Presentation.

# Car.car_sketches[0].Presentation = some presentation...
# Car.buyers[0].Presentation = some presentation...

# CarSketch and Buyer can reference the same Presentation record. Different presentation records, too. What would you define under the Presentation model? T
```

Comment: Your example would be much easier to understand if you replaced A, B, C, D with meaningful names that describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The reason I'm using letters is because by using names I get too confused! the relationships work, but if using names for my models the relationships still work but when reading it, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If the names don't make sense *you're doing it wrong*. :) You mention Presentation and CarSketch. What are they?. Are there others? How are they related? Start from there.

Comment: What is confusing you about the following association: a car sketch belongs to a presentation and a presentation can have many car sketches?

Comment: The fact that a presentation doesn't really have many car sketches. I would never access that information. I just need the references to get from a given CarSketch to a Presentation.

Comment: CarSketch and Presentation need to be separate? There is `has_one` association too.

Comment: There could be two CarSketch records and both point to the same Presentation. I currently have that a Presentation has many Buyers and car_sketches. It works.. but if you read it, a presentation has many buyers? doesn't make sense.

Comment: Would be better to update the question properly replacing A with Car etc. Way to hassling to remember/correlate the question text with your update.

Comment: Think a second what presentation really is? Is it a happening at a certain time? Are there multiple sketches presented? Who is participating? One buyer? Multiple?

Comment: Interesting, Heikki. Basically, someone creates a CarSketch for a particular Car, if the Presentation ( physical information means Presentation here ) isn't available, one is created based on the requirements. Once the CarSketch is finished (filled), the information is saved. The buyers model is simply a list of buyers that selected a Presentation for the car.

Comment: Done editing. Hopefully all is well. Please check @Eduardito

Comment: I was just about to make the replacements but you already did! thanks Zabba!!

Comment: I'm trying to push this slightly back to real world because the question starts from the models and associations that don't make sense. Car must be an existing car. Is CarSketch then a drawing of that car? What is Presentation (in the real world)? Buyer is clear but what does it mean that they select a Presentation?

Comment: Ok. Assuming a Car was just added to a store. Originally, it doesn't have any buyers ( because there are no Presentations available ). When the admin wants to start selling a particular model of the car, first it needs a CarSketch for it and a Presentation for that CarSketch. Once this is created, a buyer can buy a Car with that presentation. the CarSketch relationship with a Presentation is for internal use by the seller of the car. A buyer doesn't select a CarSketch when buying the car, but the presentation directly. No presentations will exist without a CarSketch first.

Comment: The buyer will buy a Car, but selecting the Presentation directly. He never sees the CarSketch because that is used by the Car sellers before selling a particular presentation of the Car. Think of presentation as a model of a car.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but you can expand on this and see if it is a correct understanding. (Much easier to understand a story :) Maybe you take this and weave the store in your question and then I delete this "answer".

```
There's a bunch of Cars and a bunch of Buyers.
Then there is a Maserati.
Sally the Sketcher creates a CarSketch for the Maserati.
    Q: So, Maserati can every only have one sketch.
Now Matt the Manager creates a PowerPoint Presentation containing that sketch.
    Q: So, a presentation can only be for one sketch.
Now, Matt shows Richie Rich the PowerPoint presentation. Richie likes (and is linked to that presentation)
    Q: Now there could be many more buyers linked to that presentation (they all have been shown the presentation)
```